# jquery get max date from list of dates and insert into cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

Been trying this for a couple of days without success... I need this to be in jquery 3.4

I have an html table cell with multiple dates,

```
table id="mytable"<br>
row id="1"<br>
cell class="dates"<br>
each date is a p.important_date
<br>

Wednesday, 2018/07/25<br>
Tuesday, 2020/09/22<br>
Thursday, 2019/03/14<br>
Tuesday, 2018/05/15<br>
```

( dates aren't in order and always different so i need to calculate max date on the cell.. )

In this case I need to:

```
<br>

alternative a) insert "Tuesday, 2020/09/22" into another cell, eg $('#1.latest p').html('Tuesday, 2020/09/22');<br>

alternative b) delete the other dates and only leave "Tuesday, 2020/09/22", (selecting cell, running something like $('#1.dates .important_date').each(function() { ... }).promise().done( function(){ ... });
```

I can't manage to select the max date..been trying to `split p.important_date` after , but whatever I try I always get `Invalid date` .

**UPDATE: I'm answering my own question below, here's the snippet, hope it helps someone in the future...**

```js
$('.important_date').each(function() {
    $(".dates_array").append(
        "<li>"+
            ($(this).html().split(", ")[1]).replace(/-/g, "/")
        +"</li>"
    );
}).promise().done( function(){

var justdates = [];

$('li').each(function(i, elem) { justdates.push([$(elem).text()]); 
}).promise().done( function(){

function findmaxdate(){
var data = justdates;
var dates = [];
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { dates.push(new Date(data[i][0])); }
var maxDate=new Date(Math.max.apply(null,dates));

//alert(maxDate); 
$(".max_date").append(maxDate);
}

$(findmaxdate);

}); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="long_dates">
<p class="important_date">Wednesday, 2018-07-25</p>
<p class="important_date">Tuesday, 2021-09-22</p>
<p class="important_date">Thursday, 2015-03-14</p>
<p class="important_date">Tuesday, 2018-05-15</p>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="dates_array"></div>
<br><br>
<div class="max_date"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use moment and loop through your array of dates checking which one is the latest

https://momentjs.com

Something along these lines:

```
  function getLatest() {
    const myDates = [
      1540165303000,
      1571701303000,
      1603323703000,
      1634859703000
    ]

    let latest = null;

    myDates.map(date => {
        console.log({date, latestDate})
      // If latest is not set.
      if (!latest) {
        latest = moment(date);
        return;
      }
        // If looped date is bigger than what set on latest
      if (moment(date).diff(latest) > 0) {
        latest = date;
      }

    })
    console.log('latest date', moment(latest).format('DD/MM/YY'))
  }
```

Here's a fiddle I set up to test this
https://jsfiddle.net/k2t6n98s/4/

Comment: Thank you mate, the idea this time wasn't to add another library but thanks for the input, I didn't knew momentjs, might be useful in the future :)

Comment: I see. Handling dates is as pain in JS, most people resort to libraries. Good luck with your project :)

Comment: Well, I also just noticed that with my example using timestamps moment wouldn`t be necessary, just find the biggest value ahah